Move Multiple Keyframes using a value
I've made a geometry nodes asset which consist of multiple planes scattered around a point, I then applied a material to it which is a simple emissive gradient spherical texture. At frame 0, the emission strength is at 10 while at frame 10, it is at a strength of 0. This asset is kinda like fireworks in a way, as in I need a lot of them with each having different colors or emission strength values at different frames. As of now if I wanted to have another asset within a different frame, id need a different texture every time I want to do that. Which is  why I am wondering, is it possible to move keyframes, like how you move them with your mouse but with a value instead ?

Shader editor and the Timeline

Value I want to use to move said keyframes

Please share all the relevant information including the node setup you are using. Moving keyframes is not how things like this are done. You should aim to atchieve your goals other way. You have access to scene time from geometry nodes so you can animate with geometry nodes. In order to advice people will still need to know your precise situation. This is no different than your previous question you deleted. You should provide the full context if you want to get help, because without it it's not possible.

Did you mean to say "mouse" instead of "mouth" in your question?  Please edit.

@Martynas Žiemys Again I apologize for the inconvenience, my question has been answered but I'Il make sure to give as much details as needed for my next question.

@james_t oops that is my bad lol, I corrected it.

Here is a solution that uses an animated custom property on the object that I named "EmissionValue" and where for each copy of the object I adjusted the value inserted keyframes at the desired frame number.

I include my blender example: 

Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for!
